# PHP run shell command with multible arguments on an HTML forum

Tags: php, shell

I'm new to PHP but I want to see if something like this is possible. I have to run a shell command with multiple arguments that you can change on an HTML forum like such.

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="cmd1">
    <input type="text" name="cmd2">
    <input type="text" name="cmd3">
    <input type="text" name="cmd4">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It has to run a shell command for example -

```
shell_exec('example $cmd1, $cmd2, $cmd3, $cmd4')
```

I do not understand much PHP but is something like this possible? And if it is, how would I be able to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the hook between the [`$_POST`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) variables and your variables `$cmd1`, `$cmd2`, `$cmd3`, and `$cmd4`

These can be assigned like so:

```
$cmd1 = $_POST['cmd1'];
$cmd2 = $_POST['cmd2'];
$cmd3 = $_POST['cmd3'];
$cmd4 = $_POST['cmd4'];
```

Then you need to also be aware of how things are [concatenated](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) in PHP, which is by using a [`.`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) so your [`shell_exec`](https://secure.php.net/shell_exec) example:

```
shell_exec('example $cmd1, $cmd2, $cmd3, $cmd4');
```

Should be written like this:

```
shell_exec('example '.$cmd1.', '.$cmd2.', '.$cmd3.', '.$cmd4');
```

#### WARNING: EXECUTING SHELL COMMANDS FROM WEB SUBMITTED CONTENT CAN BE VERY UNSAFE IF YOU DO NOT PROPERLY CHECK THE VARIABLES BEFORE EXECUTING THE SHELL SCRIPT!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I do understand the security issues with this, I can assure you I am going to be the only one using the page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can execute shell commands unless your application runs in safe mode:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

As you can see the shell command as a string is the only argument that can be sent to the function. However, the command itself may have a number of arguments depending on what you're using.

The command is just a string so you can build this any way you want in your PHP script. Just post your form to the PHP file and do whatever needs to be done there.

E.g.:

```
$cmd = 'myCommand ' . $_POST['cmd1'] . ' ' . $_POST['cmd2'];
shell_exec($cmd);
```

If each of your inputs contain a command then you have to do each on its own.

**BIG WARNING** This could potentially be very unsafe unless you strictly validate the input.